# Python using variables from parent class in child class

Tags: python

How would you be able to access variables from the parent class in a method in the child class?

For example, something like this:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def firstMethod(self):
        print(Parent.y) # or something?
```

Thanks.

Comment: There aren't separate parent and child instance variables.

Comment: @AriGold: that won't work, because `Parent.__init__` never runs. The `Child()` class never invokes it. since there are *no `x` and `y` attributes set* the answer here is: you can't, because you constructed `Child` in such a way that it never got those attributes.

Comment: The question then is: Why did you give `Child` an empty `__init__` method?

Comment: sure Martijn, didn't saw it direct

Answer (score 8):

First: To actually initialize the variables you need to make sure `Parent.__init__` is actually run, for example by not overriding `__init__` and then just access it as `self.y`:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Child(Parent):

    def firstMethod(self):
        print(self.y)
```

The other possibility is to call the parents `__init__` but still access it via `self.y`:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x, y)
        # additional processing

    def firstMethod(self):
        print(self.y)
```

Comment: Thanks. From your answer, how would I be able to do some like this; creating an instance of the Parent and Child class `p = Parent(1,2)` and `c=Child()` and then accessing the variable like `c.x`?

Comment: You'd need to create a `c = Child(1,2)` and then access `c.x` or `c.y`. If you want `Parent` and `Child` to be different entities you shouldn't use inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        # initialize Parent with your needed data           
        Parent.__init__(self, x,y)
        # or call mata class
        # super().__init__(x,y)

    def firstMethod(self):
        print(self.y) # or something?

c = Child(20,20)
c.firstMethod()
# 20
```

Comment: I haven't downvoted but I think using `super` makes more sense than hardcoding the parent class name. Note that sometimes people flag/downvote code-only-answers so it would be helpful to include some narrative to explain why and what you changed.

Comment: sure Manuel,  my goal was to visualize the technique, I thought its better to understand

Answer (score 0):

Following MSeifert's magnificent answer.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self): # this way,the Child overrides. So the Child Class has no instance variables. you can use super() to allow access to its Parent/Base class
        pass

    def firstMethod(self, x, y):
        super().__init(x, y)
        print(self.x, self.y)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. I don't think that is a good idea calling the constructor from another method. See How to Answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer There is also a typo: it should be super().__init__(x, y)